# Given a group G, show that the conjugacy class of g5 cannot be of size 1.

Tags: group-theory

We have a group $G$ with identity $e$ and $|G|=24$. We have 5 conjugacy classes $\mathcal{C}_{1}, \mathcal{C}_{2}, \mathcal{C}_{3}, \mathcal{C}_{4}, \mathcal{C}_{5}$, with representative elements $g_{1}=e, g_{2}, g_{3}, g_{4}, g_{5}=g_{4}^{2}$.

We have$ |C_{G}(g_{2})|=4, |C_{G}(g_{3})|=3$

The question then asks to show that $|\mathcal{C}_{5}| \neq 1$.

By the orbit stabiliser theorem we have that $|\mathcal{C}_{1}|=1,$ $|\mathcal{C}_{2}|=6$ and $|\mathcal{C}_{3}|=8$

Then by the class equation $|\mathcal{C}_{4}| + |\mathcal{C}_{5}| =9$.

But from here I'm not sure how to show that $|\mathcal{C}_{5}| \neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one element in $C_5$ then that element is in the centre, and the centre of the group consists of two elements. The centre of the group is a normal subgroup of the centraliser of any element, so all the centralisers would have to have even order. But one of the centralisers you have been given has odd order.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me to think of the centre of the group as a subgroup of each of the centralisers!